# Variable with name "status" being set to a paragraph DOM element not letting textContent be edited

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have HTML paragraphs, in which I want to inject text using `element.textContent`.
I get the paragraphs in JS with this code :

```
var status = document.getElementById("status");
var bio = document.getElementById("bio");
```

Then, I inject the text in it this way (where req.repsonseText is a JSON result from an XMLHttpRequest, and .profile.status is a string in this answer) :

status.textContent = JSON.parse(req.responseText).profile.status;

The paragraph's text doesn't change.
Any help ? (Already found a solution below)

Edit: Reformed question to be more useful for more people.

Comment: Why haven't you stored the value from `JSON.parse()` to a variable? It would be much easier to refer the object that way.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not really a helpful statement. Is there an error in the console? Are the paragraph filled with *Not specified* or simply blank?

Comment: @PierreC. Nothing is in the console, and the paragraph is filled with its value set in the html, "loading"

Comment: Is the readyStateChange listener executed? have you checked the passed data?

Comment: @Teemu there's req.onreadystatechange, do you talk about this ?

Comment: Yes, I do talk about that specific function, is it executed? And is the data passed as you expect?

Comment: What you mean you don't know ...? Check it then.

Comment: How do i check ?

Comment: Use console.log or what ever ...

Comment: put `console.log(req.readyState, req.status, req.responseText)` on a new line right after `onreadystatechange= ...`

Comment: @Teemu Thanks for your help ! I reformed the whole question and found an answer, can you tell me how it is ? Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, `window.status` is really a read-only property (I'm sorry I didn't notice it 18 months ago= ), trying to override it silently fails. This can be handled easily, just don't declare any global variables. You really don't need any globals. You would ever need to declare a single global per window only in a case when you're interacting with multiple `window` objects, i.e. iframes or pop-ups.

Comment: @Teemu Ah yes, that's another solution ;) Thank you :)
Sorry for bothering you, at the time I first posted this I didn't know anything about debugging to find the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the variable name to something else solved the problem. I think this is because the name `status` is a DOM interface variable, I believe [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_status.asp). Though that would be weird since that isn't supported by browsers anymore, but whatever.